# Conditional formatting based group values

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

In my sheet, I have groups of rows based on the value of column C (if all of the values of column C match, they are manually grouped together). What I would like, is to format the cell in column G if there is a duplicate value within that column of that particular group.  You will probably have to look at [my spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Za3a9d3hKJCMAxy72sIRH9L61wLwvBw02Fwj_9E_z-4/edit#gid=2010641565&range=G6) for this to make any sense.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to highlight all duplicates:

```
=countifs($C$2:$C,$C2,$G$2:$G,$G2)>1
```

If you just want to highlight it only if there is the same pair of values in a previous row:

```
=countifs($C$1:$C1,$C2,$G$1:$G1,$G2)
```

Remember the secret of conditional formatting with custom formulas is that it works exactly as if you had entered the formula in the top left hand corner of the range and pulled it down and across. Don't usually need array formulas or other fancy stuff.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for both answers!  I originally thought I would only want the duplicate (second entry) highlighted, but having the original highlighted as well will make it easier to locate as the sheet grows.  Thanks again!